# SSIS file with no deliminator, how(is it possible) to read using files source?

Tags: ssis, flat-file, fixed-width

I have got a feed (for Employee details) whose one record is like this.

```
101EnggAnal
```

brief given to me is 1st 3 characters will be employee ID, next 4 will be department and last 4 will be Designation. Can I read this using Flat file source? If yes how? Do i have to write Script Component as Source to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing some nuance in your question, you are simply looking at a [flat file connection manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms183343.aspx) with a format of Ragged right, or possibly Fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the easiest way is to read it as one column, and in a Data Flow task use Derived Columns on the Source to generate the 3 columns you want via expressions before using those as the columns for the Destination.